# Macro function missing in call graph

Tags: c, doxygen

Doxygen version used: 1.8.11

I have the following code:

```
void func();   

void main ()
{
    func();
}
```

When I run Doxygen graph generation, output is correct:

[image]

However, if I use a function macro:

```
void func();   
#define  MACRO func

void main ()
{
    MACRO();
}
```

Output is incorrect since the called function is missing:

[image]

How should I set preprocessor flags for this to work? Any combination I tried has failed so far.

Thanks

---

Edit: added code after preprocessing

```
# 1 "test.c"
# 1 "<built-in>"
# 1 "<command-line>"
# 1 "/usr/include/stdc-predef.h" 1 3 4
# 1 "<command-line>" 2
# 1 "test.c"

void func();

void main ()
{
 func();
}
```

Comment: can you please add the `doxygen` command used?

Comment: what does your source code look like after the preprocessing stage?

Comment: Did you try reordering? `#define  MACRO func void MACRO(); ` (newline in between of course) would be functionally identical. What does doxygen do for that?

Comment: I am using Doxygen GUI.
Reordering does not help.
Added code after preprocessing in my original question.

Comment: This is a known problem in doxygen. Some background doxygen has a scanner for the syntax and this uses the preprocessed code (when preprocessing is enabled) and a scanner to display the the source code (and this should obviously be on the non preprocessed code). The later code scanner is, historically grown, also used for determination of the call / caller graphs.

Comment: @DimaLechtchinski please add the used doxygen version (as a reference).

Comment: Added version in original question: 1.8.11

Comment: @DimaLechtchinski doxygen version 1.8.11 is quite old (December 30, 2015) I would, independently of your issue, advise to update to a newer version (currently 1.9.3)

Comment: @albert same issue exists in 1.9.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have clang installed on your system, you can enable the `CLANG_ASSISTED_PARSING` option in the Doxyfile, which is more accurate but a bit slower than the doxygen builtin preprocessor. This generates the correct call graph on my system.

Comment: This solved my problem. Thank you!